# How can I Get capture image in the next page using Flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

- I made a Login screen,
- want to Launch camera(font) on click of ***Activate Button*** , then how to show the capture image in next page?
- I am done with the  camera open part , **onPressed** of Activate Button and also done **routing** to the next page
  ----> that's mean in my case **Activate** button , doing 2 things--> (1) its captured image and (2) going to the next page

---

- Now how can I Show the Capture image in next page which I routing with loginPage **Activate** button

  ```
  class LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {

       File imagefile;






      _openCamera(BuildContext context)async{
          var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
          setState(() {
            imagefile = picture;
          });

        }






       showImage(){
        if(imagefile == null){
          return Text("No Image selected here");

        }else {
          Image.file(imagefile,width:400,height:400);
        }
      }




     var textLength = 6;
     var mobileLength = 10;


     @override
    Widget build(context) {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 0.0,
            right: 43.0,
            left: 43), 



        child: Column(
          children: [

            userField(),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0)),

            numberField(),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, )),



            activateButton(),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, )),


            showImage(),

          ],
        ),
      );
    }







    Widget activateButton() {
      return RaisedButton(
        color: Color(0xFFF4D3AE),
        child: Text('Activate',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Californian FB',
              color: Colors.black, //Color(0xFF425c5a),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, //bold
              letterSpacing: 2.0,
              fontSize: 17.0,
            )),

        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 75.0,
            vertical:
                15.0), //Activate button box will take more space horizontally & vertically.

        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),

        onPressed: () {
           _openCamera(context);
           Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/CameraAccess");

        },
      );
    }
  }
  ```

---

----------------------- This is my second page code:-----------------------------------

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class CameraAccess extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
 createState() {
    return CameraAccessState();
  }
}



class CameraAccessState extends State<CameraAccess>{
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF425c5a), 


      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Container(child: 
            Text('Your Image here',
             style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Californian FB',
            color: Colors.black, //Color(0xFF425c5a),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, //bold
            letterSpacing: 2.0,
            fontSize: 27.0,
          )
          ),




            ),
          ),

        ]
     )
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass imagefile  as arguments in pushNamed() function.
Follow link for more detail: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: appreciate your help, but now it shows the image file text name , maybe because of my secondPage this line I think---->  body: new Text("${widget.value}"),                                             ANY recommendation?

Comment: Replace your Text widget with Image widget